# How to link GitHub Repo to EC2?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

I am trying to accomplish something I thought would be really simple, but has turned into a major hassle that has me stumped. I am trying to create the simplest basic Git workflow example using a Github repository, an EC2 instance with LAMP stack installed, and a single index.html file titled "HELLO WORLD". I have successfully created the repo on Github and connected it to my local repository. However, despite my searches and attempted tutorials I am unable to push changes directly from Github to EC2. I have installed git on EC2 and even added a "Deploy Key" on GitHub, but nothing seems to happen. Clearly I am missing something here. Can ANYONE recommend a simple way to connect Git and EC2 FOR DUMMIES!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links can help? You might have already seen #2.

1. [Codedeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/) is a service which *seems* to fit your use case.
2. A [gist](https://gist.github.com/nichtich/5290675) speaking about deploying a php app.